# enableChangeDataCapture' not valid in version 38.0

Tags: sobject

I’m not sure what causes this error message and I’m trying to deploy my app and getting this error message in Jenkins.

All Component Failures:

‘1.  objects/Employment__c.object -- Error: Property 'enableChangeDataCapture' not valid in version 38.0’

Any idea what causes?

Answer (score 8):

The `enableChangeDataCapture` property is only available as of API version 41.0.

Errors like this typically happen when the package.xml you use to retrieve metadata with has a different version than the package.xml you use to deploy the metadata with.

In this case you are retrieving with at least 41.0 and deploying with 38.0.

You should update the version in one of the package.xml files so they're both the same. This ensures that the properties in the metadata are valid for the version you are deploying.

## Update

As of API 45.0, this property no longer exists and if you have it, you'll need to remove it to be able to deploy using API 45.0+

Comment: This also applies to DX projects. The API version used to deploy or do a push is configured in your `sfdx-project.json` via key `sourceApiVersion`